# Writting byte array to txt file gives weird characters (c#)

Tags: c#, file, filestream

I have a large array of bytes with different numbers (0-256). First I create .txt file with File.WriteAllText and write few lines of text. After that I want to save my byte array to this file after the text, but when I open it with notepad, there are weird characters in it. Is this a problem with encoding?

```
String filename = "filename.txt";
String text = "Some metadata........" + Environment.NewLine;
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures), filename), text);

using (var stream = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures), filename), FileMode.Append))
    {
        stream.Write(data_tmp, 0, data_tmp.Length);
        stream.Close();
    }
```

This is what I see, when I open .txt with notepad:

Some metadata........

øÀþð?øÀüà?ø€üàð€üà~ðüÀ~ð?øÀ~ð?øÀþà?øÀüàø€üàðüà~ð?üÀ~ð?øÀþð?øÀþà?øÀüàø€üàðüÀ~ð?øÀ~ð?øÀþà?þà?ø€üàð€üà~ðüÀ~ð?øÀ~ð?øÀþà?øÀüà?ø€üàð€üà~ð?üÀ~ð?øÀþð?øÀþà?øÀüàø€üàðüà~ð?üÀ~ð?øÀþà?øÀüà?ø€üàð€üà~ðüÀ~ð?øÀ~ð?øÀþà?øÀüàø€üàðüà~ð?üÀ~ð?øÀþð?øÀþà?ø€üàð€üà~ðüÀ~ð?øÀ~ð?øÀþà?øÀüà?ø€üàð€üà~ð?üÀ~ð?øÀþð?øÀþà?øÀüàø€üàðüà~ð?üÀ~ð?øÀþà?øÀüà?ø€üàð€üà~ðüÀ~ð?øÀ~ð?øÀþà?øÀüàø€üàðüà~ð?üÀ~ð?øÀþð?øÀþà?øÀüàø€üàðüÀ~ð?øÀ~ð?øÀþà?øÀüà?ø€üàð€üà~ðüÀ~ð?øÀ~ð?øÀþà?øÀüàø€üàðüà~ð?üÀ~ð?øÀþð?øÀþà?ø€üàð€üà~ðüÀ~ð?øÀ~ð?øÀþà?øÀüàø€üàðüà~ð?üÀ~ð?øÀþð?øÀþà?øÀüàø€üàðüÀ~ð?øÀ~ð?øÀþà?øÀüà?ø€üàð€üà~ðüÀ~ð?øÀ~ð?øÀþà?øÀüàø€üàðüà~ð?üÀ~ð?øÀþð?øÀþà?ø€üàð€üà~ðüÀ~ð?øÀ~ð?øÀþà?øÀüà?ø€üàð€üà~ð?üÀ~ð?øÀþð?øÀþà?øÀüàø€üàðüà~ð?üÀ~ð?øÀþà?øÀüà?ø€üàð€üà~ðüÀ~ð?øÀ~ð?øÀ(and so on)

Comment: What is `data_tmp`?

Comment: if you open it with notepad he trys to interpret the binaries as chars, this is what you see

Comment: There is no problem with encoding.  That is the way it works.  Strings in Net Library are one/two character object with a private property that specifies if the number of bytes for each character.  Encoding is uses to convert the string to byte array and byte array to string.  Note pad has option when opening file to specify encoding.

Comment: Would it then be better to convert bytes to string and save it like that? I would like to see those numbers in notepad.

Comment: byte[] data_tmp = new byte[327680];

Comment: if you want your byte array to be save as string just convert it to string by using System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray)

Comment: How is the file text which you expect to get look like? some kind of hex repersentation? `45 B4 E5`

Comment: @13urban27 Post your entire code. As it is right now it your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a vague one. May be you want to *encode* bytes into some text, say hexadecimal representation?

```
   String text = 
     "Some metadata........" + 
      Environment.NewLine + 
      String.Join(" ", data_tmp.Select(x => x.ToString("x2"))); // <- encoding 

   System.IO.File.WriteAllText(..., text);
```

and no `FileStream`? And so you'll have something like this:

```
   Some metadata........
   ab 45 25 e8 f0 03     // <- encoded array
```

Comment: Yes, and if you want decimal, you can even do `string.Join(" ", data_tmp)`.

Comment: Thank you, your solution is less complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to see is just the decimal representation of the bytes in that array you would have to convert them to that decimal number, then to a string, then to the byte representation of that string.

What you are doing now is interpreting the bytes in your array as a UTF8 (which is the standard encoding) representations of characters.

So supposing that the decimal representation of the bytes is what you want you could do this:

```
        Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
        byte[] data_tmp = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        String filename = "filename.txt";
        String text = "Some metadata........" + Environment.NewLine;
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(
            System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures), filename), text, utf8);

        using (var stream = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures), filename), FileMode.Append))
        {
            IEnumerable<byte[]> bytesToStringedInUtf8 = data_tmp.Select(b => utf8.GetBytes(((int)b).ToString()));
            foreach (byte[] byteToStringedInUtf8 in bytesToStringedInUtf8)
            {
                stream.Write(byteToStringedInUtf8, 0, byteToStringedInUtf8.Length);
            }
            stream.Close();
        }
```

With that the output is:

Some metadata........

1234

Comment: Thank you very much. That's it. Is there any way, I can put ", " between the numbers?

Comment: Dmitry's solution (other answer) is much simpler. `File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures), filename), text + string.Join(", ", data_tmp);` And nothing more. (Here the join uses comma `", "`.)

Comment: Yes, I tried them both and both work and as you said, Dmitry's is much simpler.

Comment: sure, you could do a string.Join before converting the strings to utf8 bytes arrays, and then convert the resulting string to a utf8 byte array like this:string commaSeperatedStringList = String.Join(", ", data_tmp.Select(b => ((int)b).ToString()));
    stream.Write(utf8.GetBytes(commaSeperatedStringList), 0, commaSeperatedStringList.Length);